# How can I display a message to the end user instead of the 404 page "error handling"

Tags: c#

I don't want to display the 404 message to the user, I want the message to be displayed in the normal page instead.

```
 public ActionResult Download(string fileName, string filePath){
    try{
        filePath = (filePath != null && filePath != "") ? Cryptography.DecryptAESFromBase64(filePath) : filePath;
        if (!filePath.Contains(fileName))
        {
            var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(filePath + "_" + fileName));
            return File(fs, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] data;
            this._documentService.DownloadAmazonObject(filePath, out data);

            return File(data, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
        }
    }

    catch{

        throw new HttpException("Couldn't find ", ex);
    }          
}
```

This is the code that I have, I keep having the `throw new HttpException` display in the yellow page.

Comment: is it execute the line in the catch?

Comment: it just display the last line in the 404 yellow page, this code is a piece of a long code

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends a lot on your whole setup. Whats happening is basically the following: The browser sends a request to your HTTP server. It might be part of your program itself or an application server which in turn hands the request over to your application after transforming the HTTP request into objects and a function call. This is called binding or deserialization.

The application works with the objects (strings in your case) and throws an Exception which the application server in turn transforms into a Response with the HttpStatus 404.

Depending on your setup you have to tell your web server resp. application server how to handle erroneous status codes by explicitly defining an error page.

The dirty alternative would be to catch the exception and return the message as part of a valid response. But that basically bypasses the way errors are handled in HTTP so I would very much discourage it.

Hope this helps a bit :-)